# I am getting Error: create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am creating a Profiles REST API
I am getting error on line 30 of serializers.py i.e the password.

This is the models.py

```
    def create_user(self,email,name,password=None):
        """Create a new user profile"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email) # normalize_email() is a helper function that converts email  1st to lowercase
        user = self.model(email=email,name=name) # self.model is the UserProfileManager class

        user.set_password(password) # set_password() is a helper function that hashes the password
        user.save(using=self.db)# save() is a helper function that saves the user to the database

        return user
```

This the serializers.py

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 

    def create(self,validated_data):
        """Create and return a new user"""
        user = models.UserProfile.objects.create_user(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
        )

        return user
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the User model class entirely here?

Comment: Did you define the user model by inheriting from the `AbstractUser` model?

Comment: Yes i used AbstractUser

Comment: Share your models

Answer (score 1):

The model `AbstractUser` has the `USERNAME_FIELD` and it's default value is 'username'.
And the `username` field should not be null in the database.
If you don't want to use the `username` field but rather use the `name` field, you can just change that field by setting the `USERNAME_FIELD` manually.

```
class YourUserModel(AbstractUserModel):
    ...

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def create_user(...):
        ...
```

I think the `REQUIRED_FIELDS` should include the `username` field, that is the `email` in your project.

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'email']
```

Comment: I have already set it to email, but same error

Comment: https://github.com/LondonAppDev/course-rest-api/blob/master/src/profiles_project/profiles_api/models.py

Comment: I am getting the same error

Comment: That's really strange.

Comment: Bro I fixed the error actually I had written the method insidethe class,but the method should have been outside the class

Comment: You mean, `create_user` function?

Comment: no the create function in the serializers.py, I did not provide the class meta above it , thats why it couldnt be seen .

Answer (score 1):

[Django Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/managers/) can be used for this purpose. `NewUserManager` is a custom django manager that is used in `UserProfile` model as follows:

```
# models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, UserManager, PermissionsMixin


class NewUserManager(UserManager):

    def create_user(self,email,name,password=None):
        """Create a new user profile"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email) 
        user = self.model(email=email,name=name) 
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
    return user


class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    
    objects = NewUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
```

Now `UserProfileSerializer` should work as expected!

Comment: I was missing ```objects = NewUserManager()```. Thanks!